# Binary search a function, depending on even and odd input

Tags: python, binary-search

I have this function `f(n) = x` use a binary search to find x that may not exist. Trouble is, `f(n)` differentiates between even and odd numbers such that `f(x) < f(x+2)` is guaranteed, but `f(x) < f(x+1)` is not.

Example with a finite list:

```
x = [0,1,1,2,3,5,4,7,6,8,13]

x[5] < x[7] but f[5] > f[6]
```

Currently I do two seperate binarySearches, one for even numbers and one for upper:

```
def binarySearch(n, lower, upper, even):
    mid = (upper+lower)//2
    if even:
        if mid % 2 != 0:
            mid += 1
    else:
        if mid % 2 != 1:
            mid += 1

    ...
```

But making sure `mid` is even or odd gives me problems with stopping and I produce StackOverflows. Where and how do I make sure this doesn't happen?

Bonus: How can I solve this without using two seperate binarySearches?

Comment: `x[5] < x[7]` and `x[5] > x[6]`, surely.

Comment: How about `(mid // 2) * 2`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the array is not that large which means additional memory space is acceptable. I suggest you separate the array before binary search just because this make problem more easy.

```
odd_list = x[::2]
even_list = x[1::2]
```

What's more, you can even use [bisect](https://docs.python.org/2/library/bisect.html) for sorted array directly.

Otherwise, I don't know what's your stopping issue because I didn't see your exit code. However, what you can do is:

```
if (lower % 2 == 0) != even:
    lower += 1
if (upper % 2 == 0) != even:
    upper -= 1
if lower > upper:
    return -1

mid = get_mid_wth_lower_and_upper()  // your code 

if x[mid] == n:
    return mid
elif x[mid] < n:
    return binarySearch(n, mid + 2, upper, even)
else:
    return binarySearch(n, lower, mid - 2, even)
```

Note that upper means the `index` of last element here but not `index+1`. There are some little changes needed if this is not your case.

Actually, there is no much difference with normal binary search. For the normal one, the edge case is the array with 0, 1 or 2 elements while here it becomes 0, 1 or 3.